# Is Coldfusion 9 compatible with MS SQL Server 2014 and 2016?

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Currently in our setup, Coldfusion 9 is connected with MS SQL Server 2008 R2. We will migrate our sql server to MS Sql server 2014/2016. Is Coldfusion 9 compatible with MS SQL Server 2014 and 2016?

Comment: If the native odbc drivers don't work, you should be able to install more modern ones and use that.

Comment: Since you are upgrading your database server to get a supported version (I presume) you should also upgrade your ColdFusion server to a supported version. And don't upgrade to ColdFusion 10, it will be out of support next month (May 2017).

Comment: Better suited for ServerFault